# Port Forward Flask Server in local network

Tags: networking, server, port-forwarding, flask

I have a Flask app

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, world!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=7777, debug=True)
```

I tried to port forward to `192.168.0.100` by doing this:

```
ssh -v -R 7777:127.0.0.1:7777 user@192.168.0.100
```

but I got nothing if I visit `http://192.168.0.100:7777`

However, if I port foward to a remote server

```
ssh -v -R 7777:127.0.0.1:7777 user@remoteserver.com
```

it works fine.

---

It seems `192.168.100` is listening on port 7777

```
netstat -tupln | grep ':7777'

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7777          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7770/2          
tcp6       0      0 ::1:7777                :::*                    LISTEN      7770/2
```

I also allow the traffic using iptables by doing this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 7777 -j ACCEPT
```

Is there something that I missed?

Comment: what about http://localhost:7777 or http://127.0.0.1:7777